# Changing refresh button handler of Extjs GridPanel top-bar paging tool

Tags: javascript, web, extjs, extjs6, extjs6-modern

I am trying to change the Refresh button handler of the Extjs GridPanel top-bar paging tool.

PREFACE:
I have created two stores for a single grid panel. One remote store fetches records from the DB and then after that loads the data onto the other local store. The reason is that I want local pagination with a lot of data.

PROBLEM:
Since the local store has no proxy on clicking the reload button in the grid's top-bar paging tool nothing happens. I need to overload/change the handler of that button to call the remote store to reload.

MORE PROBLEM:
I have only the extjs grid panel object on hand. Can't change the definition/code of the Ext.create('grid-panel',{}). Only have access to the output/grid object.
the button is visible through this command but can't change any of its properties.

`***.***.****.***.****.gridObject.getDockedComponent('toptoolbar').getPagingItems()[10].items`

*** is the namespace of the object(cant share that)

QUESTION:
Is there any way to tackle this problem or I am doomed?

Comment: If you can reference the refresh button you should just be able to assign a new handler.

Something like: 
var refreshBtn = **.***.****.***.****.gridObject.getDockedComponent('toptoolbar').getPagingItems()[10];
refreshBtn.handler = function(){console.log('new handler');}